# Filtering Live Photos

Tags: macos, ios, photos, photos.app

Is it possible to setup a **Smart Album** in the **Photos** app that would group all Live Photos? Neither app seems to provide a quick way to find all your Live Photos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with macOS Sierra 10.12.3, Apple has added a *Live Photos* Smart Album to **Photos**. It may be accessed from the **Sidebar** (**View** → **Show Sidebar**) or in **Albums** view (**View** → **Albums**).

It is still not possible to setup a *custom* Smart Album with `Live Photo` as a criterion.